# Running the Set-AzVMRunCommand command with parameters produces strange failing file on destination

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

I am using the `Set-AzVMRunCommand` command with the `-Parameter` parameter set.

Here is my code:

```
    $VMRun = Set-AzVMRunCommand `
    -ResourceGroupName $customerVirtualMachine.ResourceGroupName `
    -RunCommandName "RunPowerShellScript" `
    -VMName $customerVirtualMachine.Name `
    -Location $customerVirtualMachine.Location `
    -ScriptLocalPath "scripts\$($desinationScriptFile)" `
    -DefaultProfile $ctx `
    -OutputBlobUri $outputBlobUri `
    -ErrorBlobUri $errorBlobUri `
    -Parameter @(@{Name='PerformDataLoad'; Value='True'; }) `
    -ErrorAction Stop
```

*Please note the line above starting with `-Parameter` as this is the line that is causing me problems.*

And here is the local script that gets sent to the destination virtual machine by the `Set-  AzVMRunCommand`:

```
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
    [string]
    $PerformDataLoad
)

Write-Output "The value of PerformDataLoad is: $PerformDataLoad"
```

However, the script that ends up on the virtual machine as as follows:

```
param (; 
[Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]; 
[string]; $PerformDataLoad; ); 
; 
; 
Write-Output "The value of PerformDataLoad is: $PerformDataLoad"
```

Notice all the extra semi-colons (;).

Can anyone help me out understanding what is going on as I have spent all day on this.

cheers
Russ

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, I saw you in another post, maybe you can help me with my question above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is currently an Azure Powershell bug with multiline script files:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/21131

> **Workaround**
>
> Instead of using ScriptLocalPath parameter, use SourceScript parameter, with Get-Content "your path to script.ps1" | Out-String and everything will be fine.

---

For `-Parameter`, you may need to restructure your hash table like this:

```
-Parameter @{PerformDataLoad='True'; Param2='Value2'}
```

Comment: @cpt-whale Your answer was mostly correct as I tested it and it worked straight away. The only thing I will say is, the following line worked:

-Parameter @(@{Name='PerformDataLoad'; Value='False'; })

As I think it is a collection of hashtables?

Comment: @RuSs glad to hear it's working! To add some detail, I based what I said off of the `Set-AzVMRunCommand` docs, which shows it accepts a single hash table. Since your collection only has one key pair, it gets squashed and works fine. Depending on the cmdlet, and in this case the script you are feeding parameters to, you may find a list of hash tables `@( @{key=value}, @{key=value} )` behaves differently from a single hash table with multiple keys: `@{key1=value1;key2=value2}`, but I haven't tested what you're running or anything

Comment: @Cpt.-whale ok I will adjust mine just in case. Really appreciate your help 